# htaccess – Server Subdirectory With Different Name Than URL Subdirectory

Tags: htaccess

I have a client with an odd setup that I can’t quite figure out and I thought someone here might know the answer. I’m not sure they want the site shared, so I’ll use `example.com` for the sake of explanation.

Their wordpress URL is setup like `http://example.com/blog`.

However, on the server (Apache), the actual folder is called “wordpress” NOT ”blog”.

The `.htaccess` is located in the “wordpress” folder (full server path is `/var/www/wordpress/`) and looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /blog/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

There is no .htaccess in `/var/www/`

In General Settings they have this:

- WordPress Address: `http://example.com/blog`
- Site Address: `http://example.com/blog`

This works fine on WordPress pages, posts and categories. But some plugins (gravity forms, nextgen) will strip out the “blog” portion of the URL when using them. So for example a Gravity Form will try to submit to `http://example.com` instead of `http://example.com/blog` which will cause an error.

My guess is that `.htaccess` is configured wrong but `.htaccess` and regular expressions are my weak point.

Comment: Why not just rename the folder /wordpress/ to blog, then reset your .htaccess, from wp-admin permalinks page ? If the Gravity Forms still fails, then most likely is another plugin causing issues or somebody messed up with the wordpress core.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found that the form of the gravity forms had an action of "/"
You can either take that out with JS or do it manually, but remember that when the plugin updates, it'll be back

Comment: Please elaborate. I don't understand the answer in all detail. Thanks.

Comment: This may be specific to just gravity forms, but in search last night, if you look at the html in firebug, or view source, take a look at the <form> element and see what it's action is:

    <form action="/#gf-1">

that / was causing my problems, because it was in a subdirectory, / was the root url and not the page url.